# iOS delegate method not called

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I am trying to Implement communication between Controllers for the first time using Delegation.

I have a FirstViewController which launches FooTwoViewController after some seconds, then FooTwoViewController sends back some string to teh calling Controller.

I have implemented it but I discovered my delegate method is not being called OR I am implementing it wrongly.

Please see my code below:

```
import UIKit

protocol FooTwoViewControllerDelegate:class {
    func myVCDidFinish(_ controller: FooTwoViewController, text: String)
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, FooTwoViewControllerDelegate  {

    var textRecieved = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This launches FooTwoViewController after 2 seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let secondViewController =
                storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FooTwoViewController") as! FooTwoViewController
            self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func myVCDidFinish(_ controller: FooTwoViewController, text: String) {
        // THIS DOES NOT PRINT, WHAT AM I MISSING?
        print("Data received: \(text)")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! FooTwoViewController
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

My FooTwoViewController below:

```
import UIKit

class FooTwoViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: FooTwoViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func ClickMe(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.myVCDidFinish(self, text: "hey!") //assuming the delegate is assigned otherwise error
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

My myVCDidFinish method is not being called, please am I missing anything?

Comment: You are ***presenting*** an instance of `FooTwoViewController`, you're not ***segueing*** to it... so, `prepare(for segue:...)` doesn't get called, resulting in the delegate never being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually performing the segue.

Instead of:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
   let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FooTwoViewController") as! FooTwoViewController
   self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Replace with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
}
```

And make sure the segue is in place in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `delegate` here

```
let secondViewController =  storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FooTwoViewController") as! FooTwoViewController
secondViewController.delegate = self
self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

as `prepare(for segue` is called only with `performSegue` like

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"mySegue",sender:nil)

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! FooTwoViewController
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```